Of what age was Anna the Prophetess of Luke 2?
We read in Luke 2:36-37 (NCV) of an event that took place during the Presentation of Jesus at the Temple:

36 There was a prophetess, Anna, from the family of Phanuel in the tribe of Asher. Anna was very old. She had once been married for seven years. 37 Then her husband died, and she was a widow for eighty-four years.

Many versions present Anna as 84 years of age. But then, verse 36 only says that she was very old. If Anna was a widow for 84 years after having lived with her late husband for seven years after marriage, she would be above 105 supposing the marriageable age of girls is 14.
Of what age was Anna the Prophetess of Luke 2?

ως ετων ογδοηκοντατεσσαρων is in the genitive - 'a widow of about 84 years'. This description is separate from the description of her marriage. The two pieces of information are given separately. She was 84 and departed not from the temple. The NCV translation is an inaccurate paraphrase.

@NigelJ is this to say that the statement cannot be read as "a widow for 84 years" or only that "a widow of 84 years" makes more sense? I find it hard to believe that so many translators didn't recognize the genitive case. (AMPC, CSB, ISV, TLB, MSG, NET, NCV, RGT,  NMB,WE, WEB etc)

@DanFefferman Many, many traditions pass from generation to generation without question. The genitive is the genitive. T here are two descriptions of the woman. One involves marriage. One involves herself, as an individual. As to the individual : 1. She is a widow. 2. She is 84. 3. She lives in the temple. . . . . . .  Simple. Otherwise, she is about 110. . . . . . . . (Which is perfectly possible and hardly worth arguing about, if that's what one wishes to insist.)

. . . . . and, of course there is the uncertainty (about). If the exact length of the marriage is known then presumably the date of the death of the husband is known. Thence the time of her widowhood would be accurately known. There would be no 'about'. What was uncertain, therefore, is the date of her birth. Therefore the doubt is the length of her life. Ergo, she is about 84. (Not about 110.) Quod erat demonstrandum.

@Nigelj I agree that 84 is probably right. My Greek is not good enough to know if the alternate reading is mistaken or just unlikely. Thanks for your explanation.

@DanFefferman Thank you. You are welcome. Regards.

Here is my translation of Luke 2:36, 37 -

And was Anna, a prophetess, daughter of Phanuel, of the tribe of
Asher, she being greatly advanced in years, having lived with a
husband seven years from the marriage of herself, and she a widow of
about eighty-four years, who ...

Note that the meaning of the last phrase could equally mean that she was:

a widow that was 84 years old, or,
she had been widowed for 84 years

Both are grammatically possible.  Note the the comment of the Expositor's Greek Testament:

Luke 2:37. ἕως: either a widow for eighty-four years (Godet), or, as
most think, a widow till the eighty-fourth year of her life. The
former rendering would make her very old: married, say, at sixteen,
seven years a wife, eighty-four years a widow = 107

Now, while both meanings are grammatically possible, the latter (widowed for 84 years) would make her exceedingly old but unlikely.  Therefore, the first possibility is more likely that she was 84 years old.

+1 ... Glad to know that either reading is possible. I hate to think that so many translators would simply get it wrong.

Prince Philip surrendered his driving license only after getting into an accident at the age of 97 ! I wish to believe that 84 years for a lady would not have been considered worth mentioning as ' greatly advanced ' in Jesus' days.
